# Does CentOS 8 have a package for entr?

Tags: centos

When I was using CentOS 7, there was a package available for [`entr`](https://bitbucket.org/eradman/entr/src/default/). There doesn't seem to be a package available for CentOS 8.

Was this just not packaged for CentOS 8?

Answer (score 0):

I could successfully install and run the binary RPM package `entr` from CentOS 7.

Download link to the current version: https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/entr-4.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm

```
wget https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/entr-4.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
dnf localinstall entr-4.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Found the download link via:
https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/entr-4.4-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html